# How to force a resched after an interrupt in the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, task, switch-statement, interrupt

I'm playing with kretprobes and I am facing a problem. I would like, in response to certain events from a user process (e.g. specific syscalls), read data from that process address space. Since in the kretprobe entry handler we're in interrupt context, I can't possibly get the user pages from here (it may sleep) so I defer the work in the system_rq (schedule_work()).

To be sure that the user process won't change its memory before my deferred work is done, I put it in TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE and use set_tsk_need_resched(). I was expecting that during the iret, the flag would be tested and the scheduler would elect another task. It seems like it does not work like that and the user task is back on the cpu right after the interrupt, changing its memory before I had a chance to look at it.

Is there something else to do to ensure the task switch occurs directly after the iret?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found today that it is actually the good way to do this. The problem I had with the process carrying on running was because I was not in interrupt context: the kprobe was optimized (i.e. a jmp instruction instead of an int3 on x86) which caused my code to be executed in user context in kernel land. This should have been handled smoothly if the kprobe_optimized() function had worked correctly, in which case we can call schedule() directly after setting the task to INTERRUPTIBLE instead of ireturning and letting the prologue of the interrupt handler check the flag `TIF_NEED_RESCHED`. Indeed the `kprobe_optimized()` returns false in any cases if it is a kretprobe, which is due to the way a kretprobe is handled internally: it uses an aggregator of kprobes, which flag for optimized is set correctly for the aggregator but not for the kprobes within the list. I workarounded this by exporting the function `get_kprobe()` and using it to retrieve the address of the kprobe aggregator, from which I am finally able to check correctly if it is optimized or not.

I think the best way (performance wise) to fix this in the kernel is to replicate the optimized flag from the aggregator to each kprobe it lists. This way the `kprobe_optimized()` will return the proper value. Another way to do this would be to add more code in `kprobe_optimized()` to check if this kprobe is part of an aggregator list and check the aggregator rather than the actual kprobe.

Anyway this was fun!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fundamentally flawed. Interrupts are asynchronous in nature; even if you close the race between the interrupt return and the deferred work item, you can get the same race if the interrupt is delayed. Consider:

- USER: Set X = 1
- INTERRUPT: Schedule work
- USER: Set X = 2
- WORK QUEUE: Read X

vs

- USER: Set X = 1
- INTERRUPT: (delayed by hardware weirdness...)
- USER: Set X = 2
- INTERRUPT: Schedule work
- WORK QUEUE: Read X

Same result, no? So don't even try.

More to the point, interrupts can occur even in kernel code. If the application is in the middle of a system call that does not block and does modify memory, it *must* complete that call before it lets you block. Forcing it into interruptible state risks deadlocks; the kernel code may be holding a spinlock or otherwise not be in a safe state to schedule out.

Note that this is precisely why interrupt handlers cannot sleep - they would force their calling context to sleep when it may not be prepared to do so. Which is exactly what you're trying to do.

In short, the race you're thinking of cannot be solved; fundamentally your work queue item simply adds latency to the interrupt handler, which *already* has some unpredictable amount of latency. As such, the user process will always have a window in which it can mess with its memory. Further, the user process may not be in a state in which it is safe to be interrupted.

So don't worry about it - just make sure the user process can't sabotage things in a way that breaks the entire system, and leave making sure it doesn't sabotage *itself* up to the user process (ie, tell the user process's developer not to mess with this memory if he wants the hardware to work properly).

Comment: The interrupt happens *because* I put a kprobe there, so I know the user process was running and was interrupted, by my probe, and does not run while my interrupt handler is being called. From there, it should be easy to put it to sleep, like a page fault handler would do, so that I can work later on and put it back to RUNNING. Let's say you mmap a file and try to read in your AS, but the data isn't here when you try to read -> page fault -> the kernel will put you to INTERRUPTIBLE until the data arrives from the disk: it's exactly what I'm trying to achieve here. Thanks for your answer though